# how to use laravel4 resource controller to save data into database without Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Code in resource controller:

```
public function create()
{
    return View::make("register");
}


public function store()
{
    Usr::insert_data();
}
```

Code in the model file, i do not want to use Eloquent ORM:

```
class Usr {
    public static function insert_data() {
        DB::insert('insert into user (name, password) values(?, ?)', array("john", "123456789"));
    }
}
```

I try to save data into database, but after i click the submit button, it shows 500 internal Server Error.

I searched how to use resource controller on the internet, but all tutorials use Eloquent ORM for the model. Must we use Eloquent ORM model for resource controller?

Comment: have you checked your database configuration? Any information on the logs?

Comment: the resource has nothing to do with the model are you sure your form is submitting to the store method in your controller?

Comment: @user3666882, yea, i am sure the form is submitting to the store method in the controller

Comment: @chepe263, i checked the logs, it says: production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Usr' not found' in UserController.php:34

Comment: very simple then import the usr class to the controller lets say its inside the models folder then you would write this use models\usr;

Comment: make sure you namespace the usr class also

Comment: all things are good after using composer dump-autoload